# Banner propio stackoverflow en español obsoleto

Tags: bug

Estaba navegando en el sitio en inglés, el cual no tengo reputación suficiente para que me desaparezcan los anuncios y me ha salido el siguiente banner.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver tengo el sitio en oscuro y con la letra en negro no se puede leer el mensaje, debería crearse un banner adaptado al nuevo tema para poder solucionar este problema.